# Trivium reference bitstreams

Tags: stream-cipher

I am a beginner in cryptography (on my way to retirement) and have programmed the Trivium algorithm in C++ for practice. To check if the bitstream generated by my program is correct, I am looking for some bitstreams with given key ind IV. I think 200 bit length should be enough as a comparison.
Unfortunately I couldn't find anything on the net, but maybe I didn't search for the right terms.

Comment: This GitHub page seems to give test vectors for Trivium 80.80: https://github.com/bmkessler/trivium/blob/master/trivium-80.80.test-vectors

Comment: This looks like it's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: @DanielS Could you convert this into an answer? Searching for test vectors is explicitly on topic and finding them on Github is not entirely trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Test vectors for Trivium 80.80 can be found at https://github.com/bmkessler/trivium/blob/master/trivium-80.80.test-vectors for example.